# How to disable ProxyCommand for one particular host?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Using OpenSSH, I have set my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to have a `ProxyCommand` so all SSH connections go through that proxy.

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x localhost:8111 %h %p
```

But I would like to disable the proxy for one particular SSH host.

I have added the following to my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host ssh.example.org
  HostName ssh.example.org
  ProxyCommand ""
```

What should I put with `ProxyCommand` so that it doesn't use a proxy for that particular host only, but the default is still to go through the proxy for SSH conncetions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to use `ProxyCommand none` for hosts that should go outside the proxy!

```
Host ssh.example.org
  HostName ssh.example.org
  ProxyCommand none
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the lines below in: `~/.ssh/config` works for me on Ubuntu. Note that there is also ability to exclude multiple hosts/ips from the proxy setting and also the HostName is not needed:

```
Host localhost 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11
  ProxyCommand none

Host *
  ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X 5 -x localhost:8111 %h %p
```